# Retrieve %ERRORLEVEL% with complicated call in FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, psql, errorlevel

In a Windows batch file I needed to retrieve the result of a program execution into a variable, when the program call was complicated with spaces and several options. After much discussion, a workaround was found by using `CALL`:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('CALL "C:\path with spaces\foo.bat" "blah blah='foobar' blah"') do set foo=%%G
```

Please see the following question for more details and to understand the context:

[Retrieve command output to variable when command has spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33370883/421049)

In reality the batch file calls PostgreSQL 9.3, like this:

```
SET PSQL_EXE=C:\Program Files\Foo\Bar\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe
SET FOO=1
REM psql query should result in a 0 or 1 based on the mydbproperty table value
FOR /F %%G IN ('call "%PSQL_EXE%" -U pguser -d MyDB -p %PG_PORT% -c "select string_value from mydb.uri as uri, mydb.property as prop where uri.id = prop.property_uriid and uri.namespace_uri='http://example.com/foo/bar/' and uri.simplename = 'fooBar'" -q -t -w') DO SET FOO=%%G
REM next line doesn't have ERRORLEVEL set
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 EXIT !ERRORLEVEL!
```

Unfortunately it appears that this format results in a separate `cmd` instance, so any error that occurred in calling pgsql (e.g. the lack of a password file) does not get passed back and the `%ERRORLEVEL%` does not get set. Specifically pgsql prints out:

```
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Yet `%ERRORLEVEL%` (and `!ERRORLEVEL!`) is still `0`.

See the following question for more info:

[PSQL Error Level in Batch For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30767449/421049)

So now the question is how to find out the %ERRORLEVEL%, now that I've succeeding in getting the response of `psql`. I'd prefer not to write to some temporary file---I want to do everything in memory.

(Note that, yes, the value I'm trying to query from the database and store in `FOO` will be either a `0` or a `1`; not that it matters, but it does make things more confusing.)

I tried to test Aacini's proposed solution by simply seeing what would be returned in `%%G`:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('"CMD /V:ON /C CALL "%PSQL_EXE%" -U user -d MyDB -p %PG_PORT% -c "select string_value from mydb.uri as uri, mydb.database_property as prop where uri.id = prop.property_uriid and uri.namespace_uri='http://example.com/foo/bar/' and uri.simplename = 'fooBar'" -q -t -w ^& ECHO !ERRORLEVEL!"') DO (
  ECHO %%G
)
```

Because psql could not find a password file, this prints an error to stderr (as expected) and the `ECHO` outputs `0`---so the `ERRORLEVEL` is not getting sent back to the `DO` clause. But if I split out the command from the `FOR` loop and just run it directly, it shows the `ERRORLEVEL` (`2`) just fine!

```
"%PSQL_EXE%" -U user -d MyDB -p %PG_PORT% -c "select string_value from mydb.uri as uri, mydb.database_property as prop where uri.id = prop.property_uriid and uri.namespace_uri='http://example.com/foo/bar/' and uri.simplename = 'fooBar'" -q -t -w
ECHO !ERRORLEVEL!
```

Update: After being advised that I need to escape the escapes if I have delayed expansion already turned on, I took the given answer and updated it to take into account that the program I'm calling won't return a value if it generates an error. So here's what I do; first I make sure two variables are undefined:

```
SET "var1="
SET "var2="
```

Then I use the loop that @Aacini and @jeb gave, but inside the loop I do this:

```
if NOT DEFINED var1 (
  SET "var1=%%G"
) else (
  SET "var2=%%G"
)
```

Then outside the loop after it has finished:

```
if DEFINED var2 (
  ECHO received value: !var1!
  ECHO ERRORLEVEL: !var2!
) ELSE (
  ECHO ERRORLEVEL: !var1!
)
```

That seems to work. (Unbelievably---what gymnastics!)

Comment: In your original question, I posted an answer for using the short path. Did you try this instead of the call command? Also, you may want to see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226971/exit-b-not-working-correctly-when-inside-a-block-with-other-commands

Comment: Please post the code of foo.bat as well.

Comment: @Squashman, I have improved the example to use the actual executable I'm using, and almost identical arguments. You could probably reproduce this by changing `%PSQL_EXE%` to point to some batch file of your choosing, although note that the path should have spaces to accurately reflect the problem.

Comment: I suppose you are enabled delayed expansion BEFORE your FOR /F, then you have to modify the line to `FOR /F ... ('"cmd /V:on .... ^^^& echo ^!ERRORLEVEL^!"') DO (`

Comment: Yes, delayed expansion was already on. I'll experiment further with @jeb's addition information.

Comment: It seems to be dropping my commas from the quoted strings---do those need to be escaped, too?

Comment: `do those need to be escaped, too?` yes.

Comment: It seems it needs = escaped as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple tricks must be combined in order to do that. The Batch file placed in the `for /F` set is executed in a new cmd.exe context, so we need a method to report its errorlevel when such command ends. The only way to do that is by first executing the desired Batch file via a `cmd.exe /C` placed explicitly, and *after it* insert a command that report its errorlevel. However, the commands placed in the `for /F` set are executed in the *command-line context*, not in the Batch file context, so it is necessary to enable delayed expansion (`/V:ON` switch) in the explicit cmd.exe. After that, a simple `echo !errorlevel!` show the errorlevel returned by the Batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "foo="
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('"CMD /V:ON /C CALL "path with spaces\foo.bat" "blah blah='foobar' blah" ^& echo !errorlevel!"') do (
   if not defined foo (
      set "foo=%%G"
   ) else (
      set "errlevel=%%G"
   )
)

echo String output from foo.bat: "%foo%"
echo Errorlevel returned by foo.bat: %errlevel%
```

This is "path with spaces\foo.bat":

```
@echo off
echo String from foo.bat
exit /B 12345
```

And this is the output of previous code:

```
String output from foo.bat: "String from foo.bat"
Errorlevel returned by foo.bat: 12345
```

**If delayed expansion is already enabled** before in the main batch file then a quite different syntax have to be used.
`^!ERRORLEVEL^!` This is necessary to avoid, that the !ERRORLEVEL! is evaluated in the context of the batch file, before the FOR line will be executed.
`^^^&` is necessary to bring a single `^&` to the inner `cmd /V:ON` expression

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "foo="
REM *** More carets must be used in the next line ****
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('"CMD /V:ON /C CALL "path with spaces\foo.bat" "blah blah='foobar' blah" ^^^& echo ^!errorlevel^!"') do (
   if not defined foo (
      set "foo=%%G"
   ) else (
      set "errlevel=%%G"
   )
)
```

**EDIT**: *Reply to OP's comments*

My first solution *assumes* that the program always output one line, so it took the errorlevel from the second output line. However, the *new specification* indicate that when the program ends because an error, the first output line is not sent. It is very easy to fix this detail, and the corrected code is below.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "foo="
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('"CMD /V:ON /C CALL "path with spaces\foo.bat" "blah blah='foobar' blah" ^^^& echo errlevel=^!errorlevel^!"') do (
   set "str=%%G"
   if "!str:~0,8!" equ "errlevel" (
      set "errlevel=!str:~9!"
   ) else (
      set "foo=%%G"
   )
)

echo String output from foo.bat: "%foo%"
echo Errorlevel returned by foo.bat: %errlevel%
```

However, the original specification indicate that the executed program **is a BATCH file** called `"C:\path with spaces\foo.bat"`. This code correctly works when the executed program is a Batch .BAT file as requested, but it does not work if the executed program is an .exe file, as I clearly indicated in my first comment: "Note that C:\path with spaces\foo.bat must be a .bat file! This method don't works if such file is an .exe". This way, you just need to create the "foo.bat" file with the execution of the .exe and an `exit /B %errorlevel%` command in the next line. Of course, if you directly test this method by directly executing the .exe program, it never will work...

**2ND EDIT**: *Some explanations added*

The purpose of this solution is that giving a Batch file `"C:\path with spaces\foo.bat"` that show some output and return an errorlevel value, like this one:

```
@echo off
echo String from foo.bat
exit /B 12345
```

... it may be called by another Batch file that get both the output and the errorlevel. This can be done in a very easy way using an auxiliary file:

```
@echo off

call "C:\path with spaces\foo.bat" > foo.txt
set errlevel=%errorlevel%
set /P "foo=" < foo.txt

echo String output from foo.bat: "%foo%"
echo Errorlevel returned by foo.bat: %errlevel%
```

However, the request indicate: "not to write to some temporary file---I want to do everything in memory".

The way to get the output from another command is via `FOR /F`, like this:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('CALL "C:\path with spaces\foo.bat" "blah blah='foobar' blah"') do set foo=%%G
```

However, The Batch file placed in the FOR /F set is executed in a new cmd.exe context. To be more precise, the execution of `foo.bat` in previous FOR command is *entirely equivalent* to the next code:

```
CMD /C CALL "C:\path with spaces\foo.bat" "blah blah='foobar' blah" > tempFile & TYPE tempFile & DEL tempFile
```

Each line in `tempFile` is assigned to the `%%G` replaceable parameter and the `set foo=%%G` command is executed. Note that previous line is executed as if it was entered at the command-prompt (*command-line context*), so several commands does not work in this context (like goto/call to a label, setlocal/endlocal, etc) and delayed expansion is set to the initial value of cmd.exe, usually disabled.

In order to simplify the following description, we use a shorter, but similar `FOR /F` command that is shown with the equivalent internal code of the execution of `foo.bat` below it:

```
FOR /F %%G in ('CALL "foo.bat"') do set foo=%%G
-> CMD /C CALL "foo.bat"                <- we also omit the "tempFile" parts
```

This way, we need a method to report the errorlevel of `foo.bat` when such command ends. The only way to do that is by first executing the desired Batch file via a `cmd.exe /C` placed explicitly, and *after it* insert a command that report its errorlevel. That is:

```
FOR /F %%G IN ('"CMD /C CALL foo.bat ^& echo !errorlevel!"') do set foo=%%G
-> CMD /C "CMD /C CALL foo.bat ^& echo !errorlevel!"
```

Note that the ampersand sign must be escaped this way: `^&`; otherwise it will incorrectly split the commands placed in the set of the `FOR /F` command. In previous line both the `foo.bat` and the `echo !errorlevel!` command are executed via the nested `CMD /C`.

However, the commands placed in the FOR /F set are executed in the command-line context as explained before, so it is necessary to enable delayed expansion (`/V:ON` switch) in the explicit cmd.exe; otherwise, the `echo !errorlevel!` just not works:

```
FOR /F %%G IN ('"CMD /V:ON /C CALL foo.bat ^& echo !errorlevel!"') do set foo=%%G
-> CMD /C "CMD /V:ON /C CALL foo.bat ^& echo !errorlevel!"
```

---

Ok. Note that the previous description assumed that delayed expansion was DISABLED when the FOR /F command is executed. What are the changes if it was enabled? **1.** The `!errorlevel!` is replaced by the current errorlevel value, and **2.** Any caret that is used to escape a character is removed. These changes are done when the line is parsed, *before* the FOR /F command is executed. Lets see this point with detail:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%G IN ('"CMD /V:ON /C CALL foo.bat ^& echo !errorlevel!"') do set foo=%%G
-> After parsed:
FOR /F %%G IN ('"CMD /V:ON /C CALL foo.bat & echo 0"') do set foo=%%G
```

Previous line issue an error because the unescaped `&`, as usual. We need to preserve both the exclamation marks and *the caret* of the ampersand. Preserve exclamation marks is easy: `^!errorlevel^!`, but how we preserve the caret in `^&`? If we use `^^&` the first caret preserve the second one, but the next character to parse is `&` alone and the usual error appears! So, the right way is: `^^^&`; the first caret preserve the second one and give `^`, and the `^&` preserve the ampersand:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%G IN ('"CMD /V:ON /C CALL foo.bat ^^^& echo ^!errorlevel^!"') do set foo=%%G
-> After parsed:
FOR /F %%G IN ('"CMD /V:ON /C CALL foo.bat ^& echo !errorlevel!"') do set foo=%%G
```

Comment: Aacini, I'm afraid I can't get this to work. The entire `FOR` body was getting skipped. I updated the example in the question to better reflect what is going on in real life. You could probably change `%PSQL_EXE%` to point to some batch file of your choosing, although note that the path should have spaces to accurately reflect the problem.

Comment: I suggest you to copy my exact same code and run it to check it is working. After that, insert modifications one by one until you identify the step that cause the problem. Note that `C:\path with spaces\foo.bat` _must_ be a .bat file! This method don't works if such file is an .exe

Comment: Why is the `!errorlevel!` expanded within the `cmd` instance created by `for /F`, although the `!`s are not escaped?

Comment: @aschipfl: Note that the Batch file have _not_ delayed expansion enabled, so the `!`s are just passed as text until the internal `CMD /V:ON /C ...` execute they

Comment: Ah yes, of course, sorry; I just spotted the `setlocal` at the beginning and commented immediately -- too hasty obviously...

Comment: @Aacini, I'm having trouble understanding what your code is supposed to do. I think that under normal circumstances you expect two lines to be generated: `String from foo.bat` from `foo.bat`, and `12345` from the `ECHO` statement. But you are assuming that `foo.bat` always emits a string. In fact in my case `foo.bat` doesn't emit a value if it exits with an error code. (The error code is to indicate that it failed). In this case, how would I know if `foo` held the output or the error code, as it would be the first string returned either way?

Comment: @Aacini, your solution does not work, because the `ERRORLEVEL` is not being returned in `%%G`. Please see updated question.

Comment: With the extra escapes I am now getting the `ERRORLEVEL` back, but I need to change your logic in the loop because `foo.bat` will not emit a value if it encounters an error.

Comment: OK, I arrived at a solution; see my updated question. Someone update the answer to reflect this and I'll assign the bounty as soon as I can.

Comment: Garret: See the edit in my code.   @jeb: Thanks a lot! **`:)`**

Comment: Can you please explain what this new solution is doing? It's very cryptic. Even the first one I had to pick it apart.

Comment: Right, @Aacini... but the technical parts you explained are not the most cryptic (although they certainly are not obvious). Especially complicated is your _technique_. The developer needs to understand that the commands being executed produce multiple lines (different ones depending on error conditions or not, etc.). Your latest solution then adds special strings that must be parsed out (e.g. `str:~0,8`), assuming that `foo.bat` didn't emit the same strings. Anyway I got it to work but I opted for the longer but more understandable approach I mentioned in the updated question. Thank you!